# Why declare a 2d array as a type when passing it to a function and why include the rows and cols in the type?

Tags: c++

Basically why declare arrays as a type when passing it to a function for example,
the following code as shown below.

```
const int MAX_ROWS = 10; 
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 5; 
typedef char ItemType;

typedef char TwoDType[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];

void SetSomeVals(TwoDType twoDimAry, int rowsUsed, 
                 int num, ItemType initialValue);
```

why include the rows and cols in the type also?

Comment: You don't have to if you don't want to.

Comment: You could use [`boost::numeric::ublas`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.html) for easy-to-use matrices in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> why include the rows and cols in the type also?

You don't have to. You can use:

```
const int MAX_ROWS = 10; 
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 5; 

typedef int TwoDType[][MAX_COLUMNS];
```

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_ROWS = 10; 
const int MAX_COLUMNS = 5; 

typedef int TwoDType[][MAX_COLUMNS];

int main()
{
   TwoDType a1 = {{10}, {20}};
   std::cout << a1[0][0] << " " << a1[1][0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << sizeof(a1) << std::endl;

   TwoDType a2 = {{10}, {20}, {40}};
   std::cout << a2[0][0] << " " << a2[1][0] << " " << a2[2][0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << sizeof(a2) << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
10 20
40
10 20 40
60
```

By specifying both the row and column, you are making `TwoDType` to be an array a fixed size.